# Display an image without having it's URL cached and without Data URIs?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to download an image without having it's URL placed in the browser history and then display it in HTML/Javascript.  The URL has sensitive data in it and so it cannot be saved on the client side.  Using a POST to get the data from the server seems the best approach to not allow the URL to be saved.

Data URIs would work, except IE doesn't have strong support for them (size limitations).

Is there another way to get this done?  Is there a URI trick or a way to render using a Canvas?

EDIT:  To clarify... the data comes from a 3rd party image provider.  The sensitive data is authentication parameters that must not be stored on the client side for security purposes.

Comment: What makes you think that `<img src="sensitive/url.jpg"/>` will add anything to the browser history?

Comment: What is the server-side language? PHP, ASP, etc. You could create an "image proxy" so worst-case scenario the user sees something like `site.com/getImage.php?id=whatever` (which is actually forwarding an image retrieved from `securesite.com/private/something.jpg`)

Comment: Why is there sensitive data in the url? Any network traffic is easy enough to monitor, so hiding it is mearly a very small hurdle if the information is truly sensitive.

Comment: It's trivial for a user to see all traffic between the browser and the network. The "Tamper Data" Firefox plugin for example makes all HTTP requests quite visible.

Comment: The image comes from a 3rd party host that only give access to the images with authentication.  The authentication data must not be cached on the client side.

Comment: Also to note, the importance of "hiding" the data is from scripts that can browse the user history and access the authentication data and reuse it nefariously or from physical theft of the client device.  Hiding it from the authenticated user who is operating the web app is not the purpose.

Comment: Proxy caching is what I do now. Not a great solution because of the amount of data that needs to be grabbed from the 3rd party. But +1 to Brad for that suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the sensitive data in the URL is not the web address itself, but rather some parameters passed.
My suggestion: support a one time address with a unique key in it (something like a GUID) that will point to the image. If anyone is trying to use it again it will be useless

Example:

> http://www.my-domain.com/images/621536253-2487234-gfhgdsfhf-7853243

Comment: Good idea however the URL points to a 3rd party service.  The sensitive data is an auth key that must not be cached for security reasons.

Comment: @ricosrealm You could proxy that content through your server to hise the source. The nice version would be to have a stream come in and a stream come out to answer the image request. The simple version would be to copy the image to your server when it is requested, then serve it to answer the client request

Comment: This proxy solution is what I eventually went with to solve this issue.